# How to stream bitmap data over winsock?

Tags: c++, video-streaming, winsock2

I am working on a remote administration tool project that will stream graphics data over Winsock. However the Winsock send and recv functions only accept buffers of data type char*. How can I stream data from a bitmap over a socket?

Comment: How your Bitmap is stored in the memory?

Comment: Open the bitmap. read from the bitmap into an array of `char`. Write the array of `char` into socket. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: `send()` and `recv()` take `char*` parameters for historic reasons only, but they actually operate on raw bytes, not text characters, and thus can be passed *any* pointer to allocated memory, you just have to type-cast it to `char*`.  So, simply save your bitmap data to a flat in-memory format and `send()` it (preferably preceding it with the memory size first), then have the receiver allocate sufficient memory to `recv()` the data and load it into its UI as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you